# Menus on Windows Phone WebBrowser Not Functioning on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I have an app that incorporates the Windows Phone WebBrowser control into itself. This works great on Windows Phone 7 and functions as you would expect, however, the same app running on Windows Phone 8 does not function properly.

Whenever a user tries to access a Drop Down Menu on Windows Phone 7 they view the full screen item selector that you would expect. However, on Windows Phone 8 it simply highlights the menu box and leaves it there. The options may not be accessed.

Since the code is exactly the same I don't understand how I am receiving two different results. Is there some change to the control on Windows Phone 8 that is breaking my project?

My code is simple and looks like this:

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" IsScriptEnabled="true"/>
```

The code that is causing a problem follows this syntax:

```
<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
```

Comment: What drop down menu do you mean, exactly?

Comment: An example would be using something like <select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>. This opens the fullscreen selector on Windows Phone 7 and is ignored on Windows Phone 8.